# ImageView changes as it gets resized

Tags: android, android-imageview, scaletype

I'm using an activity background `ImageView` with a `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` but whenever I create that activity the background image changes as it gets resized. Note, I'm using as a background animation.

Is there a way to do this before the activity layout is inflated?

Comment: How and when are you loading the image in your activity life cycle?

Comment: I have the xml, and in my java code, I do `findViewById` to get the ImageView and start an `Animation`